# Find query with UTC time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem. I store my data in the database in GMT +2.

But I want to grab it from the database in GMT 0 or UTC to support any offset in the future.
If i have
`"time" : ISODate("2017-06-11T10:39:57.000Z")`

But it's in GMT +2,
    And i want to:

```
_schema.find({time:{$gt:2017-06-11T09:00:00.000Z}) in GMT 0.
```

Comment: No. It's stored in the database as UTC. You might have created it in a timezone which was +2 difference at the time, but it still stores as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, mongodb stores timestamps in UTC.

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/):

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.

Observe:

```
> db.events.insert({my_date: new Date('Sun Jun 11 2017 12:37:15 GMT+0300 (MSK)')})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.events.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593d0f98cb81c56e86d5d414"), "my_date" : ISODate("2017-06-11T09:37:15Z") }
```

Comment: when i send the data to the mongodb i send data (11/06/2017 12:37:15)
i dont spesefy the date gmt :/ i dont control the app sadly.
so when i get the "utc" it returns (11/06/2017 12:37:15)

Comment: @edan: well, if you don't specify the timezone, then it likely defaults to utc. Your fault. Fix the app.

Comment: If i had control on the app i would have sadly i cant.
but they send me the GMT in a defrent colmn and i thout if there a posibilety to Query(date_colomn-GMT_ colomn) to get utc?

Comment: @edan: nope, can't do that. Your only option now, it seems, is postprocessing results in the app. Fetch timestamps from your db and apply the delta.

Comment: thank you ill have to do that in the end i gess or ill change there mindes :P thanks alot!!